# How to implement a Date Range Picker using mat-calendar in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, calendar, angular-calendar

I would like to implement a Daterange picker using mat-calendar in Angular. I am not able to get implement it in a correct way. Can anyone help me in this.

My html code:

```
<mat-calendar [selected]="range"
[comparisonStart]="range.start"
[comparisonStart]="range.end"
(selectedChange)="onChange($event)"></mat-calendar>
```

My Ts Code:

```
range: DateRange<Date>;
constructor(){}
ngOnInit(){
}
 onChange(event)
 {
  console.log(event);
 }
```

Comment: The official documentation didn't help? https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

Comment: Yes I read it but it did not help.

Comment: I do not know if you still need that, but I found a way to create an inline ranged calendar with angular material calendar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67484281/how-to-implement-ranged-inline-calendar-with-angular-material/67584842#67584842

Answer (score 23):

You have to provide a range selection strategy to get the preview working.

```js
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY,
      useClass: DefaultMatCalendarRangeStrategy,
    },
  ],
```

Then, you'd have to do some converting of `Date` to `DateRange`.

```js
  selectedDateRange: DateRange<Date>;

  _onSelectedChange(date: Date): void {
    if (
      this.selectedDateRange &&
      this.selectedDateRange.start &&
      date > this.selectedDateRange.start &&
      !this.selectedDateRange.end
    ) {
      this.selectedDateRange = new DateRange(
        this.selectedDateRange.start,
        date
      );
    } else {
      this.selectedDateRange = new DateRange(date, null);
    }
  }
```

```html
<mat-calendar (selectedChange)="_onSelectedChange($event)"
              [selected]="selectedDateRange">
</mat-calendar>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Note: mat date range picker only work on Angular 10 and above**

***.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date">
    <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>

  <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.start.hasError('matStartDateInvalid')">Invalid start date</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.end.hasError('matEndDateInvalid')">Invalid end date</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<button (click)="save()">Save</button>
<p>Selected range: {{range.value | json}}</p>
```

***.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  range = new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl(),
    end: new FormControl()
  });
  constructor(){

  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/dmojaobybmm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-forms-example.ts

Comment: I know this concept on how to do date range picker what i need is I need to implement range selector in mat-calendar

Answer (score -1):

i follow here https://github.com/angular/components/issues/20307#issuecomment-674040060

here's a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/components-issue-q9db1k.

if u want code inside Onchange, here is my code

just process with logic :D here is my code:

```
<mat-calendar #calendar [selected]="selectedDateCalendar" (selectedChange)="toggleStartDateDate($event, calendar)">
```

in ts: just declare start,
end,
selectDateType

```
toggleStartDateDate(date: any, calendar: any) {
const selected_date = moment(date).toDate()
if (this.selectDateType === "startDateAfter") {
  this.start = selected_date
  this.end = selected_date
  this.selectDateType = "startDateBefore"
} else {
  if (moment(date).isBefore(moment(this.start))) {
    this.start = selected_date
    this.end = selected_date
    this.selectDateType = "startDateBefore"
  } else {
    this.end = selected_date
    this.selectDateType = "startDateAfter"
  }
}
this.selectedDateCalendar = new DateRange(moment(this.start), moment(this.end))
calendar.updateTodaysDate()}
```