# Is there a way to use date range from angular material without the input box?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

Currently i'm using  mat-date-range-input for date range selection

```
    <mat-form-field appearance='fill' style='width:1px;visibility:hidden;'>
      <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
      <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]='picker'>
        <input matStartDate placeholder='Start date'>
        <input matEndDate placeholder='End date'>
      </mat-date-range-input>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]='picker' matSuffix></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

but the issue is i dont want the input box and need just an icon for  enabling date range selection

Comment: I think this topic answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66167592/how-to-implement-a-date-range-picker-using-mat-calendar-in-angular

Answer (score 2):

Just set **hidden** property on **mat-date-range-input** nad use ngModel for setting the values.